# ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero , i am using bias_correction package in python

Tags: replace, error-handling, division

I am working on rainfall data bias correction in python using bias_correction  package and i am getting this error since my data is daily rainfall observed data(1970-01-01 to 2020-12-31) so there are somany days with "0" values, so how to solve this problem. Can anyone help me sorting out this problem

Want to solve this problem so if anybody knows how to solve this error kindly guide me